# Tracking object's location in Objective C (How to prevent program from quitting)

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Let's say I wanted to track the location of my car as I drive around the city, just for kicks.

I have an old iphone 5, so I write up a little program using Parse.com framework, and using geopoints easily construct a little collection of data which I save to my cloud server. Piece of cake, right?

Well, my question is this: I put the phone on the seat after I begin to run the program. How do I ensure that the phone does not go to sleep? And what happens to my program if the app goes to sleep/quits? And how would I prevent this, if such a thing might occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Apple's "Background Execution" abilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). A great example of this is Spotify: users can select a song, change apps, and put their phone to sleep. All the while Spotify continues to play that song.

In your case it sounds like you want location tracking, most likely using the "Significant-change location service". Using the location framework with background execution enabled will allow your application to save those geo-points to Parse at specific, distance-triggered points, even if the application is in the background or the phone's asleep.